# Django Model instanciation from json

Tags: django-models, django-3.0

I have downloaded data using `manage.py dumpdata some_app.SomeModel > some_app_SomeModel.json` for several models and am trying to programmatically load the files like so :

```
with open('some_app_SomeModel.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    json_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

    for model_data in json_data:
        model_data = model_data['fields']
        SomeModel.objects.create(**model_data)
```

Unfortunately this does not work for foreign key fields : the id value is not turned into the corresponding model instance and I get `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "SomeModel.fk_field" must be a "FK_Model" instance.` where "1" is the json value of the fk field.

How to simply fix this ?

Comment: Does your JSON data contains the primary key? If not, these might end up getting linked to the wrong objects.

Comment: The primary key of SomeModel to be loaded you mean ? If so, yes as i comes from dumpdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fk_field`, then you can assign to `fk_field_id`, hence you can rewrite this to:

```
with open('some_app_SomeModel.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    json_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

    for model_data in json_data:
        model_data = model_data['fields']
        model_data['fk_field_id'] = model_data.pop('fk_field')
        SomeModel.objects.create(**model_data)
```

Note that your items should contain a primary key, otherwise it is not said that these will link to the object with the primary key in the JSON file.

Comment: Actually i have 'fk_field' in the json coming from dumpdata and it holds the fk value (e.g. 1)

Comment: @FredSullet: what I mean is, it makes not much sense that the `fk_field` holds for example 1, if the other data does not contain the primary key, and `1` can thus refer to an arbitrary object.

Comment: Yes @Willem I agree. Django `datadump` should produce `fk_field_id`. Proof is your solution works ! But no news saying Django fixtures (among others) are bugged/unfinished